# Getting error with @Mapper import statement "import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;"

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mybatis

I am not sure why I am getting an error with this import statement "import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;". Although the "import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.*;" is working fine but the "@Mapper" annotation is not working.[image]

Comment: Have a look this https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/841

Comment: Can you share your , build.gradle file or pom.xml files ? Have you tried re improting the project ? Can you build in terminal ? Sometimes IDE have problems with importing.

Comment: How to share the complete file here

Comment: @Aayush `@Mapper` was added in 3.4.0, so be sure to use a recent version of MyBatis (3.5.7 is the latest).  If you are using a recent version already, please add the details about the error. "not working" is almost always useless as an issue description, you know. :)